# What is the best way to keep ViewModel Collection in sync with Model

Tags: .net, wpf

In my application, I have a model object that contains a collection lets say `List<Chair>` that gets updated frequently. ViewModel has an `ObservableCollection<ChairViewModel>` that wraps `List<Chair>`.

Since `List<Chair>` gets updated frequently, I need to keep `ObservableCollection<ChairViewModel>` in sync with it so that every change in `List<Chair>` gets reflected on WPF UI.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the specifics of your application as you'll be dealing with trade-offs for which only you'll have sufficient information to choose between.

Some approaches I've used in the past are:

- Have the model provide fine-grained notifications of changes and have the VMs subscribe to those notifications
- Have a service layer that your view models call into to get model data. The service layer can periodically update its cache from the model
- Delay communications with the model as long as possible and attempt to automatically synchronize a local cache with the model

There are many approaches, but choosing the right one for your application is the key.